# How does a Lyapunov vector evolve along a trajectory?

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems

**First I introduce the Lyapunov vectors.** Here I follow the notations of a [previous answer I got on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/375176/lyapunov-vectors-along-a-trajectory).

We have a dynamic system with discrete time $t$ (integer values). The
time evolution is defined by a (local) diffeomorphism $T$:
$$
x(t+1) = T[x(t)] \tag{1}
$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
This gives rise to a one-parameter group $T^t$ of (local) diffeomorphisms.

We define the matrices $Y_{i,j}(x,t)$ as the derivative maps of these diffeomorphisms.
I assume that the sequence $Y(x,t)$ is Lyapunov regular. For fixed $x$,
it is known that there are a (single) symmetric matrix $\Lambda(x)$ and a matrix $\Delta(x,t)$ such that:
$$
Y(x,t) = \Delta(x,t) \cdot \Lambda(x)^t \tag{2}
$$
with
$$
\log \|\Delta(x,t)\|,\log\|\Delta^{-1}(x,t)\|=o(t) \;. \tag{3}
$$

The eigenvectors of $\Lambda(x)$ should be the Lyapunov vectors
(please correct me if I'm wrong).

**Now my question is: how do such vectors evolve along a trajectory?**

I mean this: if $v(x)$ is an eigenvector of $\Lambda(x)$, is there a $v[T(x)]$, eigenvector of $\Lambda[T(x)]$, that can be somehow calculated from $v(x)$?

For what I understand, such vectors are the "covariant Lyapunov vectors". If this is correct, then each of them, say $v$, should evolve according to:
$$
v[x(t+1)] = X[x(t)] \cdot v[x(t)]
\tag{4}
$$
where $X(x)=Y(x,1)$, or equivalently:
$$
v[T(x)] = X(x) \cdot v(x) \, .
\tag{4bis}
$$

Actually, I never saw this claim explicitly written anywhere in this form, so I'm wondering if this is correct.

I found no way to prove it but **I tried to do the following**. First, I use the property that $Y$ is a cocycle:
$$
Y(x,t+1) = Y[T(x),t] \cdot X(x)
\tag{5}
$$
thus finding:
$$
\Delta(x,t+1) \cdot \Lambda(x)^{(t+1)} = \Delta[T(x),t)] \cdot \Lambda[T(x)]^t X(x)
\, .
\tag{6}
$$
This equation contains $X(x)$, as Eq. 4, however I do not know how to go on to prove Eq. 4.

**I do not expect that an answer contains the proof, but at least that it confirms that Eq. 4 holds, e.g. by providing a reference, or that it is wrong.**